# Powershell Sort and transpose data based on particular column

Tags: powershell

I am new to powershell. I have a data which is in columnar format, which needs to be converted into rows by sorting it numerically.
**Input data:**

```
Fruit month amount
1apple jan 10 
3blueberry jan 20
4mango jan 30
2banana jan 50
1apple feb 20 
3blueberry feb 50
4mango feb 80
2banana feb 95
```

Desired Output:

```
Fruit JanAmount FebAmount
1apple 10 20
2banana 50 95
3blueberry 20 50
4mango 30 80
```

Can anyone pls help me with this?

Comment: so there's no space between `Fruit` and number values in the original data? and extra whitespace between lines?

Comment: This looks like homework, that would be ok if you show your code or even the attempt of it.

Comment: Code: get-content $InSort | sort Fruit
(here $insort is my input file and i am sorting by 1st column i.e fruit)
we can take tab or modify it as , as demiliter

Comment: Please edit the question to include new information, so other don't need to read through all the comments. Fruit month amount are headers in the file? And you don't want to restrict to just jan and feb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as there are no whitespace in the fruit-names then you can read the file as CSV with whitespace as delimiter. Then merge them using `Group-Object` and `Add-Member` to dynamically add x months. Ex:

```
Import-Csv -Path $InSort -Delimiter " " |
#Group all records per fruit
Group-Object Fruit |
#Sort by fruitname
Sort-Object Name |
#Process each group (fruit) to merge the rows
ForEach-Object {
    #Create object (row) per fruit
    $obj = New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property @{
        Fruit = $_.Name
    }

    #For each record (month), add amount column
    $_.Group | ForEach-Object {
        #Turn month-value into TitleCase (first letter uppercase)
        $month = (Get-Culture).TextInfo.ToTitleCase($_.Month)
        #Add amount-column per record (month)
        Add-Member -InputObject $obj -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "$($Month)Amount" -Value $_.Amount
    }

    #Output new objects
    $obj
} | Export-CSV -Path newfile.csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter " "
```

Output:

```
Fruit      JanAmount FebAmount
-----      --------- ---------
1apple     10        20       
2banana    50        95       
3blueberry 20        50       
4mango     30        80
```

Comment: Thanks Frode.
It works fine in cmd line. but when i export that to a text tile, it comes like this. Wish we had an option to attach the file in this site

@{Fruit=1apple; JanAmount=10; FebAmount=20}
@{Fruit=2banana; JanAmount=50; FebAmount=95}
@{Fruit=3blueberry; JanAmount=20; FebAmount=50}
@{Fruit=4mango; JanAmount=30; FebAmount=80}

Comment: Sorry, i missed to see that. My actual file is huge. around 600MB. So, i use .txt format

Comment: This worked just by changing the extension to .txt
Thanks a ton :) :)

Comment: So change it to `newfile.txt`. File extension is just cosmetic. Also, this solution will be slow and require some memory with a file of that size. Please include these kinds of details in a future questions....

Comment: I am stuck another issue where i have column1 as year, column3 as Month
Is there a way where i can concatenate columns?

2015, xx, Jan

2015, yy, Feb

It should create a new column like this

2015Jan,2015, xx, Jan

2015Feb,2015, yy, Feb

Comment: Do you need "YearMonthAmount"-columns? This was not part of the question. I've already given you the tools to read file, add columns etc. Please try to modify it yourself first and come back if you get stuck on a specific problem.

Comment: Thanks :) That was not part of my original question. Was curious to know. I'll try to figure out myself

Answer (score 0):

if you delimiter into your file is space, try this:

```
import-csv "C:\Temp\yourfile.txt" -Delimiter  ' ' | 
    group fruit |
        select Name, @{N="JanAmount";E={($_.Group | where month -eq 'jan').amount}} , @{N="FebAmount";E={($_.Group | where month -eq 'feb').amount}}
```